# How to use eBay API to get item variation images in GetSellerList?

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I can't get variation specific images on an item

item.Variations.Pictures returns an empty Collection, not a PicturesType object that it says it returns in the docs.

```
foreach (ItemType item in sellerlist)
    {
    if (item.Variations != null)
    {
        // item.Variations.Pictures is meant to return PicturesType object not a collection
        PicturesTypeCollection b = item.Variations.Pictures;
        Console.WriteLine(b.Count); // = 0


        //if (f != null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetSellerList call does not return item.Variations, according to [this article](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/9745/getsellerlist-variation-information-not-being-retu.html) from eBay dev support in 2014.

Which is stupid because this call has an includeVariations property, Variations object etc.

But using GetItem call instead works.